# How to get the ID from table by passing Name in Entity Framework in Silverlight mvvm?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm

In my Silverlight with MVVM project, I'm using Entity Framework.  I have one table named Customer, with fields CustomerID, Username, age.  I have inserted one row programmatically.

Here the `CustomerID` field is an auto-incremented one.  So how can I get the `CustomerID` value by passing `UserName` that was inserted?

Need the LINQ Query to get it from Entity Framework..?

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto-incremented ID should be set in the object, after you call `SubmitChanges`.  That is, for example, `newId` here should contain the value:

```
var customer = new Customer { Username = "test", Age = 100 };
dataContext.InsertOnSubmit(customer);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
var newId = customer.CustomerID;
```

If you need to get load it subsequently from the database, then use a simple query:

```
string name = "test";
var customer = dataContext.Customers.Where(customer => customer.Username == test).FirstOrDefault();
if (customer != null)
{
    var newId = customer.CustomerID;
}
```